# How to do the raster package identify all bands (layers) of a image?

Tags: r, package, layer, raster, rgdal

i'm trying to use de raster package to read a multilayer (multiband) image (ENVI format [.hdr]) that have 160 values of refletance and 160 values of wavelength per pixel, but when i use the code that i developed, the program returns only 1 band and the refletance value associated.`section1=raster("./x")
getValuesBlock(section1, row=1, nrows=1, col=1, ncol=1 )`

Comment: You should provide the code used to read the files and, better, provide also access to the data.

Comment: Use `brick` instead of `raster`. And please read `?brick`.

Comment: Thank's a lot Pascal. Your tip solved my problem. Thank's Paulo Cardoso.

Comment: Guys, i studied all results that i received and concluded that i found the wavelength and i didn't find the reflectance values. How can i get the reflectance values associated to the wavelength?

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the looks of it , it seems to me that you want to read a particular band of a raster file into the R environment ,

```
require("raster")
dir.file<-"dir/file.hdf"
#Reading the first band of the raster image
band1<-raster(dir.file,band=1)
```

Change the values of the`band` parameter of the `raster()` method to control the band id of your raster.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To create a multi-layer Raster object, you should use the `brick` function if they layers are in one file, or the `stack` function if they are in multiple files.

```
library(raster)
# example file name
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
b <- brick(f)
b

# a single cell value
b[1]
```